# Hiding Table Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table that I'm using to show details from the line items of a quote. I want to hide a particular row depending on the value of the field in it. The expression I've tried is to set the row visibility to:

```
=IIF(isnothing(First(Fields!NEW_PRICEBREAKS.Value, "QuoteDetail")),true,false)
```

When I run the query from the dataset "Null" returns for NEW_PRICEBREAKS for most of the records.

Also, when I expanded the row with another column with this expression:

```
=IIF(isnothing(First(Fields!NEW_PRICEBREAKS.Value, "QuoteDetail")),"is nothing","not nothing")
```

I see "not nothing" repeated over and over again. I've attempted to use TRIM inside of the isnothing to remove spaces and it still doesn't work.

Also, the sql data type for NEW_PRICEBREAKS is nvarchar(MAX).

Any ideas how I can suppress this row correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the FIRST function was inserted in there so I was always receiving the first New_PriceBreaks value which was not nothing. When I removed it, the behavior was as expected.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in `First`. in this expression all columns are compared with First row!!!
try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!NEW_PRICEBREAKS.Value <> nothing ,false,true)
```